# Setting System Property for the specific JVM

Tags: java, batch-file, properties, jvm

I have a java program that executes a batch file in a seperate JVM. Now on setting System.setProperty() does not have any effect inside the batch file.

```
System.setProperty(key,value);
Process shutdownProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ABC.bat");
```

this process runs in a seperate JVM.
In the bat file am executing a java program, where i access `-System.getProperty(key)`, but i get null value here, so how to set the System Property in that specific JVM from java, whether any parameter can be passed while executing the bat file or what can be done

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52075320/edit) your question and clarify.

Comment: System properties are per process. You need to pass properties to another process.

Comment: Perhaps, you want to use environment variables instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Runtime.getRuntime` you are accessing the environment (host, OS, ...) in which the JVM is executing. With `exec` you are launching a command in such environment. This means executing that command in a *command prompt* on Windows or in a *shell* on *nix.

You have no such 'JVM System Property' concept in the *command prompt*/*shell*. If you need to pass parameters from JVM to your bat file, one way could be to use the *command prompt* standard syntax, and parsing in the bat file. Something like the following.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ABC.bat " + key + " " + value)
```

In your bat file, you will be able to retrieve key and value with the following.

```
set key=%1
set value=%2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any direct parameters like -DProperty can be passed on executing bat file? @Davide

Comment: Not in an "automatic" way. `-DProperty` parameters are properly interpreted by the JVM, but you are using your JVM to run a bat file in the OS, where `-DProperty` syntax has no particular meaning. The suggested solution is the simplest one. You can for sure implement something that is more robust and better fits your requirements.

Comment: @user1 could you please mark this as the answer if you are ok with the answer? :-)